# Sequelize w. Postgres - cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

In a NodeJS project, I am using `Sequelize version 6.21.3` and `Postgres 11.16`.

I specify my write and read configuration as indicated in the [Sequelize docs on Read Replication](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/other-topics/read-replication/).

I am using a raw query such as :

```js
  const query = `
    INSERT INTO my_table
    (
      a, b, c
    )
    VALUES
    (
      $a, $b, $c
    )
    ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT my_constraint
    DO UPDATE
    SET 
      a=$a
    RETURNING *
  `;

 await sequelize.query(query, {
    bind: {a, b, c},
    plain: true,
  });
```

This is running perfectly fine locally but in production I get : `cannot execute INSERT in a read-only transaction`

I am not entirely sure why this is happening, but one of my hypothesis is that the request gets sent to the read replica rather than the master (write) one. Note that previously, we were using a few queries (not in a raw format) and this error wasn't happening. However, we wanted to move forward with this raw query to reduce the amount of sql statements necessary to handle a request.

It was under my assumption that all raw queries would be forwarded to my write replica. Isn't that not the case ?

If someone has insights on what could be happening, I would be very grateful. Big thanks in advance ! :)

Answer (score 1):

> *It was under my assumption that all raw queries would be forwarded to*
> *my write replica. Isn't that not the case ?*

The [documentation](https://sequelize.org/api/v6/class/src/sequelize.js%7Esequelize#instance-method-query) says about the `plain` option set to `true`:

> Sets the query type to SELECT and return a single row

Presumably this takes precedence over the default `RAW` value for `type` in how it indicates that the query is read-only. I would remove `plain: true` from the options in your case.

Comment: This seems to be it indeed :) Huge thanks. I wonder though, what's the proper way to return a single result from the query. I thought using `plain: true` was the way to go. Ideally I wouldn't want to do some array manipulations after sequelize returns. I would just like to have my result directly.